# Using Antiforgery with Ajax or AngularJs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery my asp.net core .net framework application, add to the configure services

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Add framework services.
  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
  services.AddTransient<ISession, JwtSession>(s => JwtSession.Factory());
  //services.AddCors();
  services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
  services.AddMvc();
}
```

I want to use it in a controller and did as follow:

```
    [Route("[action]"), Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      var f = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
      return View();
    }
```

But do not know how to put the key into view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you would like Antiforgery to work with Ajax scenarios. Following is an example:

In Startup.cs:

```
 // Angular's default header name for sending the XSRF token.
 services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

A filter to generate antiforgery token cookie:

```
public class GenerateAntiforgeryTokenCookieForAjaxAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var antiforgery = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAntiforgery>();

        // We can send the request token as a JavaScript-readable cookie, and Angular will use it by default.
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context.HttpContext);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
            "XSRF-TOKEN",
            tokens.RequestToken,
            new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
    }
}
```

Usage of the filter:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [GenerateAntiforgeryTokenCookieForAjax]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Product product)
    {
```

Comment: And don't forget to add "using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" otherwise generic GetService extension will not be available.